# What is the purpose of the WWW subdomain?

Tags: domain-name, www, subdomain

What's the point of having `www.`? Isn't it just useless extra text? Since everyone is used to it, `www.google.com` looks more well-balanced than `google.com`, but why did it start in the first place?

One thing I noticed, is that `google.com` has the IP of `74.125.53.100`, in the UK, while `www.google.com` has the IP of `209.85.135.106`, in the US. Could anyone explain a bit on that?

**Edit:** Is `example.tld` supposed to be a different machine than `www.example.tld`? Does it have to be?

Comment: Nice question. I'm curious about abbreviating "world wide web" to something which (of course is shorter on paper/screen) is actually 3 times longer to say out loud. Maybe the only example of this in the English language. Other languages don't have this issue of course. Any good ways to simplify?

Comment: Isn't a cname a type of subdomain?

Comment: Yes, `www.` is a subdomain, and it does not matter if it's got its own address (`A`/`AAAA`) records or if it's simply `CNAME`d to somewhere else. It stays a subdomain.

Comment: Technically speaking, I think Dan may be correct: www would refer to a computer (a host) either directly (via an A record) or indirectly (via a CNAME record; an alias), so it would be a hostname, or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).  It could still be that subdomain is a general term for any domain name that has a parent domain though.

Comment: Doesn't the domain name point to the server/host?

Comment: @mk12 Only if you explicitly point it there in DNS. Most domains *do* as a matter of good practice, but it's not required or mandatory.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Before the World Wide Web, there was still an Internet, and it was used for a variety of things:  telnet, email, gopher, FTP, etc.  At that time, it was traditional to assign domain name aliases to servers for common functions.  So, *smtp.example.com* would be example.com's outbound email SMTP server, *ftp.example.com* would be example.com's FTP server, etc.

When the Web came along (early 1990's), it was just yet another application / protocol — it wasn't necessarily envisioned at that time that it would become the most popular thing to use the Internet for, next to email. So, an organization's web server was assigned a domain name alias of *www.* like any other service would have typically been assigned.

Over time many sites started dropping the *www.*, because URLs are after all often typed in by people and yes it's 4 more characters than really necessary.  But, *www.* still lingers today and it's not likely to ever completely go away.

Comment: In agreement with bm. The domain (eg google.com) handles many services and the www kind of says which service it is using (www, mail, smpt, pop, ftp...). Of course, as www traffic is probably the most common kind, servers will most likely know what is expected, and act accordingly. Many servers are configured to redirect traffic from (eg) google.com to www.google.com. One reason for this is that search engines often see google.com and www.google.com as different sites (which is bad, for reasons not relevant here). Sites leaving off the www are becoming more common eg superuser.com!

Comment: So the www means it is for the web, for the http protocol, and also to separate it from subdomains (for cookies), but now some servers (like superuser) are not using the www (although makng it redirect to the plain non-www) because they are only intended for that.

Comment: @Mk12: You bring up an interesting point - the `http://` protocol is intended for web traffic, whereas the other popular subdomains have their own protocols like `ftp://`. Are there many cases where HTTP is appropriate for non-website traffic?

Comment: http is for hyper text, html. So no matter what will be received is plain html. I don't really get what you mean about 'ther\ir own protocols', ftp is the file transfer protocol.

Comment: Indeed, the internet was totally unexpected in the capacity it is today. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet

Comment: I am suprised nobody mentioned anything  about  XSRF and relevance to same origin subdomains.

Comment: This is worded weirdly. There's STILL and Internet today, and it's still separate to the www :)

Comment: @mk12. Despite the fact that http is used mostly for serving html pages (and associated assets), this doesn't necessarily need to be always the case: you can also serve xml, json or any other format understood by the http client (which is not always a browser). It really depends on the content-type.

Comment: @mk12 [HTTP is "_HyperText Transfer Protocol_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), and has no particular ties with HTML... You often download images, CSS and JavaScript over HTTP; APIs / services often use JSON / XML to pass data from machine to machine; etc...

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. It is superfluous to have smtp.example.com, www.example.com, ftp.example.com, etc. because all the protocols operate on different ports, right?

Comment: You are right, historicaly www. Add

Comment: You are right. Historically www added like other sub-domains (FTP, SMTP, etc.). But technically, we can have all of them on root domain on different ports(80, 21, 25)

Answer (score 25):

It is mostly used to separate cookies from the other subdomains.

If you are going to use cookies, definitely keep the `www.`.

You can always use an 301 redirect to redirect the short domain to the one with `www.`, that way your users don't have to type it.

This will allow you to create sub-domains that are cookie-less for static data serving. Without a `www.`, cookies are served on all sub-domains. Therefore, if you are not using the `www.`, you need a completely separate domain name to have a cookie-less domain versus just using a sub-domain.

Other than that, choosing between keeping the `www.` or not is just a question on which one you prefer. Just make sure to redirect the one not chosen to the other one using a 301 redirect.

**EDIT:**

To explain, setting a cookie uses a hierarchy for how the cookie is propagated to domain.

For example, setting a cookie to `example.com` effectively allows the transfer of cookies to:

```
example.com
www.example.com
sub.www.example.com
my.example.com
oh.my.example.com
images.example.com
hello.example.com
```

Versus setting a cookie to `www.example.com` only allows the cookie in those situations:

```
www.example.com
sub.www.example.com
```

By using a `www.` you are allowing yourself to use sub-domains to have different cookies from the main site (and none at all if so desired).

Without `www.` (or another sub-domain), all cookies set on the domain will propagate to the sub-domains.

Comment: Huh?  www. was in use before cookies existed -- from the dawn of the web in fact -- as far as I know.

Comment: Yup, but now it’s a decent convention for keeping cookies separate if you end up using subdomains for separate sites.

Comment: That's some really good info about the application of cookies with subdomains, but I'm afraid it doesn't really answer the question of WHY the subdomains are used how they are.

Comment: **@Lee B:** Because today, this is the only real reason why people keep using `www.` on new websites. There is no other technical reason why `www.` is still in use today.

Comment: Sorry, disagree.

Comment: @LeeB. Andrew is correct, this is the only *technical* reason why a new website creator will choose having `www` over not having it.

Comment: Cookies are a poor argument here... If you verbally say "_superuser.com_" to many people, they will still type `www.superuser.com`. This is why it's still important. How the site then handles adding or removing the prefix is up to the site. e.g: SU gives an HTTP 301.

Answer (score 10):

No idea if this is traditionally why `www.` is used, but one possible reason:

Say you have a server which runs web, SMTP and IMAP servers. Users access the web server via www.example.com, SMTP via smtp.example.com and IMAP via imap.example.com

Your server becomes heavily loaded, so you want to split the web-server to a new machine. To do this, you simply change the "www" subdomain to point to your new web-server's IP address.

For larger internal networks, this is an easy way to move servers around.. Just change the internal SMTP server DNS entry and all clients will automatically start using the new machine. No forwarding of ports to worry about

With internet facing servers, you would probably keep both servers on the same NAT'd network, and forward port 80 to a different machine, or use a load-balancer

There are benefits to retaining the "www." part of the URL for purely web-servers, particularly with regards to cookies, as [Andrew Moore](https://superuser.com/questions/60006/whats-the-purpose-of-the-www-subdomain/60028#60028) and [this blog.SO post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/) explain.. Plus if you redirect the non-www domain, users don't have to type it (and even if you don't, most browsers will try "www.example.com" if "example.com" doesn't work)

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a matter of abstraction, like having bills addressed to "The Club Secretary" instead of "Susan". If you have bills sent to susan, and sales catalogs, and CVs, then what happens if you hire Bob to handle HR stuff like CVs?  The mail is still addressed to Susan, and no one will know it's for Bob until Susan has found time to open it and make sure it's not meant for her.  So instead of naming "Susan", the actual person, you name "Human Resource Department" -- the ROLE.

Likewise, you name computers for their ROLEs, not the actual computers.  So you have a computer called www.yourcompany.com if you serve websites, and a computer called ftp.yourcompany.com if you provide an FTP service, etc.  If you don't, then one computer, yourcompany.com, has to receive all the internet traffic, and then pass it on to the right place.  www.yourcompany.com could be all the webservers at google, but if yourcompany.com is a laptop, the laptop will be overloaded, while the web servers will still be sitting around waiting for information to reach them.  Like Susan handling all the mail initially, one computer can handle all the roles initially, but the separate computer/domain names help to separate (or consolidate) things as necessary.

Comment: Since they are on different ports this isn't really an issue.

Comment: @mgb: not an issue as far as you're concerned, is what you mean.  Some of us care about doing things in elegant ways.

Comment: it's quite possible to have http over unusual ports...

Comment: so servers like www.yourcompany.com and ftp.yourcompany.com historically had different IP addresses?