# When I open some websites its being displayed WW2 instead of WWW. Why?

Tags: internet, website, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does wwws mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/353245/what-does-wwws-mean)

When I open some websites its being displayed WW2 instead of WWW. What it means and why?

Answer (score 6):

`www` and `ww2` are [subdomains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain#Overview). They have no special meaning to a browser, other than the fact that they are part of a larger domain. These days, the above subdomains are used mostly on the basis of tradition. Quoting this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692273/why-ww2-sub-domains) on StackOverflow:

> People running large(-ish) sites used to do this when they needed to
>   break up the load between more than one server. One machine would be
>   called www then the next one would be called www2, etc.
>
> Today, much better load balancing solutions are available that don't
>   require you to expose your internal machine naming conventions to the
>   browser clients.