# What does it mean when there's a number after the www in an url?

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does wwws mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/353245/what-does-wwws-mean)

ex) www47.[...]

this post mentions these types of urls - http://hostpc.com/community/showthread.php?3813-www45-www47-and-www51-and-POSSIBLY-www55 .. does this mean the number specifies which server should process requests?

Comment: These aren't duplicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means absolutely nothing.  As far as the URL and URI specification, and the HTTP URL specification are concerned, that is just a host identifier.  So, it gets passed directly to DNS, resolved, and the IP address connected to.

Now, the people why publish those URLs might assign some meaning, but that is entirely up to them.  There is nothing in the standards that causes it to mean anything more or less that `www`, or even `banana` would in the same position.