# what is the meaning of www2

Tags: internet, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does wwws mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/353245/what-does-wwws-mean)

Today I got one link from my friend that starts with www2.zzzzzzzz.co something like that

what is difference between www1, www2 and www3 in `url`

Comment: From WIKI:
WWW2 and WWW3 are hostnames or subdomains, typically used to identify a series of closely related websites within a domain, such as www.example.com, www2.example.com, and www3.example.com; the series may be continued with additional numbers: WWW4, WWW5, WWW6 etc. Traditionally, such websites are mirrors used for server load balancing. In some cases, the specific hostname may be obscured, creating the appearance that the user is viewing the "www" subdomain, even if they are actually viewing a mirror site.

Answer (score 11):

### Web farms and load balancing

Names like www1, www2, www3 are often used for members of a load-balancing farm of web-servers for popular web-sites where the workload is too much for a single server or where multiple servers are used to proivide continuity of service in the event of failure of a single server.

### An example of how it works

A front-end server at www.example.com initially receives the requests and redirects the browser to an available server in the farm, it does so by returning a HTTP redirect response to the browser, the browser then retries it's request using the redirected URL provided.

### It's just a name

It may just be that some parts of a large website are handled by different servers and rather than naming the servers shop.example.com shareholder.example.com jobs.example.com they name them www1.example.com www2.example.com etc.

Answer (score 1):

They're just sub-domains. Once upon a time sub-domains used to give a clue to the protocol used (e.g. ftp, gopher, smtp etc.) but today sub-domains are (mainly) just used to route traffic to a specific IP address.