# What does "ww35" or "ww20" mean in a URL or domain, like in ww35.mydomain.com?

Tags: dns, ip, domain, subdomain, www

What does "ww35" or "ww20" mean in a URL or domain like, in ww35.mydomain.com?

What is they used for?

Why when I visit some page using these, receive a message "This IP has been banned". Which IP is banned? The sites' IP or mine? (I mean the IP my ISP provider asign to my modem) This message is only in an specific URL's with ww35. and ww20. URL's and both are the URL resulting of a redirected domain with a common www. prefix. Is th same question, this second part of question is my concern about if this prefixes are in potentially dangerous sites to my PC.

IS a diferent question of wwws with an additional "s" because it was specific with its the relation with the protocol https, I want to know if is really the same 3 w's or 2 w's and the difference between both if it exists.

Comment: These look like 2 different questions that aren't very related. Am I right?

Comment: You should only ask one question for each, well, "question" here. For your first question, see http://superuser.com/questions/353245/what-does-wwws-mean?rq=1 it has a good and detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a hostname, picked by the server owners; similar to "WWW".  Focusing on ones named like "WW##", with no further information, those are *probably* nodes in a [web farm/cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_farm).

Re: "Why when I visit some page using these, receive a message "This IP has been banned"."

Without much more information regarding exaly how/when you're seeing this (and where) this is hard to answer for sure, but it's most likely *your* IP that's in question.  If you're on a dynamic IP from your ISP you can blame someone who had your IP before you. ;)