# What is www, what difference between www and normal http page?

Tags: www

What is `www` and what is the difference with a normal web page or site?
If i open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or [google.com](http://google.com) simply, what change?

Comment: Just do a little research on the net. :)

Comment: When you do google it here's a hint: www. is a subdomain of whatever domain it's attached to. www.domain.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does wwws mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/353245/what-does-wwws-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `www` is is a naming convention inherited from hostname/domain name setups and procedures that existed when the Internet existed, but the “World Wide Web” (aka: `www`) was a new thing.

So—for example—at one point in the early 1990s a company named `example.com` could have had a simple Internet presence for the use of users using Telnet. So a user on `example.com` could Telnet into `example.com` by running a command like `telnet example.com`. But if they used a web browser like Mosaic or Lynx at the time, they would not get any content from `example.com`.

But now `example.com` set up a web server and needs a new home for it. Since the world wide web was not as common back then as it is now, simply going to `http://example.com` would have been confusing. So instead the hostname convention of `www.example.com` was devised. This naming convention followed the logic of FTP servers being on `ftp.example.com` and such.

So flash forward to nowadays, 99% of most people online connect to a hostname/domain name purely for some type of web server access. So now accepting HTTP connections on `http://example.com` would make sense in addition to `http://www.example.com`. In many cases, systems administrators setup redirects on the non `www` hostname so `http://example.com` automatically gets redirected to `http://www.example.com`.

So in short, in most cases `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` should give you the same content. The two naming formats exist to respect historical conventions/standards in hostname/domain name practices. And many times administrators just redirect requests to `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com` to make their lives easier.

Comment: You can even see this behavior with the example used, `http://google.com`, simply entering that in the browser will give you a 403 redirect to `http(s)://www.google.com`